# Print sub-folder name and content of result.txt to .csv

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I have a folder which has multiple sub-folders and sub sub folders. I want to print the content of a file called `result.txt` which is present in many sub folders or sub sub folders into a csv file along with the name of the sub-folder.

That means if the files named `result.txt` are in

```
abc/def/result.txt
efg/result.txt
```

Then I need a csv file which should have

```
1. abc   content of its result.txt
2. efg    content of its result.txt
```

and so on.

I started with the following `find` command

```
find . -iname 'result.txt' "a portion of path" "content">final.csv
```

How should I proceed from here ?

*Note: (8th December, 2017) Although the below solutions display the content properly on the terminal , none of them work when I add >final.csv. As already mentioned, my result.txt has mutilines. The content of a particular result.txt gets spilled to different cells rather than being in a single cell. Any suggestions ?*

Comment: What if there's `a/b/result.txt` and `a/c/result.txt` as well?

Comment: the first sub-folder name is unique

Comment: I can reduce the constraints if this seems too tough. The first column in .csv can have the name of entire path.

Comment: Shouldn't a `.csv` be **c**omma **s**eparated? ;P

Comment: csv files are comma separated. Why is your example separated by spaces ? Please clarify

Comment: space is just for clarity. you can replace space by comma.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think `find` is the right choice:

```
find */ -name "result.txt" -exec bash -c 'printf "%s,%s\n" "${0%%/*}" "$(cat $0)"' {} \;
```

#### Example run

```
$ echo r1 >a/b/result.txt
$ echo r2 >c/result.txt
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── result.txt
└── c
    └── result.txt
$ find */ -name "result.txt" -exec bash -c 'printf "%s,%s\n" "${0%%/*}" "$(cat $0)"' {} \;
a,r1
c,r2
```

#### Explanations

This `find` command searches every file in or under the current directory of the name `result.txt` and `exec`utes the `printf` command in  a `bash` subshell. The `printf` command prints the subdir's name, a comma and the file content followed by a `\n`ewline. If you want to write this output to a file, just append e.g. `>final.csv` to the command.

#### Even simpler

is the `-printf` approach suggested by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver):

```
$ find */ -name 'result.txt' -printf '%H,' -exec cat {} \;
a/,r1
c/,r2
```

This prints an additional slash in the first column which you can easily remove by piping the output through e.g. `sed 's|/,|,|'`.

#### Merging multiline `result.txt` content into one cell

To replace newline characters with e.g. spaces just replace `cat` with `sed ":a;N;\$!ba;s/\n/ /g"` in one of the above commands, e.g.

```
$ find */ -name "result.txt" -exec bash -c 'printf "%s,%s\n" "${0%%/*}" "$(sed ":a;N;\$!ba;s/\n/ /g" $0)"' {} \;
a,r1 r1
c,r2
```

If you want some other string as the delimiter replace the `/ /` part with `/your_delimiter/`, but keep the slashes.

Comment: If (as the OP states in comments) there is only one occurrence of `result.txt` under each top-level directory, then you simplify that to `find */ -name 'result.txt' -printf '%H,' -exec cat {} \;` I think

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a way (now edited to turn line breaks into spaces, thanks to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/6192153)):

```
shopt -s globstar
n=0; for i in **/result.txt; do sed -e ":l;N;\$!bl;s/\n/ /g; s/.*/$((++n))\. "${i%%/*}"\t&/" "$i"; done
```

You can add a redirection to write to a file

```
n=0; for i in **/result.txt; do sed ":l;N;\$!bl;s/\n/ /g; s/.*/$((++n))\. "${i%%/*}"\t&/" "$i"; done > outfile
```

#### Notes

- `n=0` set a variable to increment
- `shopt -s globstar` Turn on recursive globbing with `**` to find all files in directories below this one (unset with `shopt -u globstar` afterwards, or exit the shell and start a new one)
- `:l` set a label for this action
- `N` read two lines into the pattern space (this allows us to use `\n`)
- `\$!` not if this is the last line of the file... we have to escape `$` because the whole command is [double quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) so that the shell can expand `$i` etc. But this `$` needs to be passed intact to `sed`, where it means "the last line of the file". I recommend using [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) for `sed` scripts unless you have to pass shell variables in them.
- `bl` ...branch to label (do it again)
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `s/\n/ /g` for all the newline characters in the pattern space (all but the last one), replace the newline with a space
- `.*` any number of any characters (anything in the file)
- `$((++n))` increment `n` with each iteration of the loop
- `\.` literal dot (commas are not treated specially by `sed`; they will be printed literally)
- `"${i%%/*}"` the name of the first subdirectory of the current one in the path of the file we are dealing with (strip all characters after the first `/`)
- `&` the matched pattern from the search section (anything in the file)
- `--` do not interpret leading `-` in subsequent arguments as prepending option flags. This prevents filenames beginning with `-` being interpreted as options. This is unnecessary in this specific case, because we are searching explicitly for `result.txt` and only files with this exact name will be passed to the loop. However, I have included it, in case anyone needs to reuse this script with a glob.

Here's a more readable version, which is also more portable (should work in all versions of `sed`) as is uses newlines instead of `;` to separate commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
n=0
for i in **/result.txt; do
         sed ":l      
              N        
              \$!bl     
              s/\n/ /g
              s/.*/$((++n))\.,"${i%%/*}",&/" -- "$i"
done > outfile
```

Comment: is there a way if the file is multi line?

Comment: the result.txt file is not too big. I want it to fill one cell only

Comment: name of sub-folder in the first column and the output of subfolder's unique mutltiline result.txt file in next column. One result.txt file should fill only 1 cell.

Comment: @Zanna Just delete line breaks. That's what I would do.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy it is non-trivial to delete linebreaks in `sed`. But I'm working on it ;)

Comment: @Zanna If there's someone who can figure it out via sed, it's you :) Because you're awesome

Comment: @user8109 OK I've got it :)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash script solution

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# If $1 is not given, find will assume cwd
print_file(){
    local inputfile="$1"
    while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];do
        printf "%s\\" "$line"
    done < "$inputfile"
}

get_file_info(){
    local filepath="$1"
    counter=$((counter+1))
    parent=${filepath%/*}
    if [ "$parent" = "$filepath"  ]; then
        parent="."
    fi
    printf "%d,%s," "$counter" "$parent"
}

main(){
    if [ -z "$1"  ];then
        set "."
    fi

    find "$1" -type f -name "result.txt" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d ''  path
    do
        get_file_info "$path"
        print_file "$path"
        printf "\n"
    done
}

main "$@"
```

The way this works is that you should save this as file, for example `results2csv.sh`, make executable with `chmod +x` and run either by giving full path to the script or place it into `~/bin` folder, run `source ~/.bashrc` and call the script by name.

Here's how this script works:

```
$ ./result2csv.sh things                                                    
1,things/thing2,to be or not to be\that's Boolean logic\
2,things/thing1,one potato\two potato\
```

Give the script the top-most directory, and it will go through the subdirectories finding the files and output the path to file in accordance with how you specified top most directory. So, for example if you specified `./things` as top most, it would result in first line having `./thing/things2` as path to file.  Newlines are replaced with backslashes to show file contents. Note that it will also assume current working directory "." if directory isn't specified.

```
$ cd things
$ ../result2csv.sh                                                          
1,./thing2,to be or not to be\that's Boolean logic\
2,./thing1,one potato\two potato\
```

All you have to do now, is call `results2csv.sh  directory > output.csv` to output data into a file, and you're done

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly how to do it with just terminal commands, but I have done similar thing using python script from this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644441/python-run-script-in-all-subdirectories

With this you can easily add funcionality to write lines to CSV file:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html for Python 2

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for Python 3

Comment: It's good to reference old work you've done and Python is very much welcome here, but it's better if you actually adapt code to suit particular question, and post it in the answer, not just provide a link